Continue on Error in Automic JobStep after script call with non-zero return code
I do have an automic job step which calls a BTEQ script (but just think of any kind of script which return an error code). Something like:
BTEQ "filename"

Now I want to introduce some monitoring/logging, which is basically calling another BTEQ which writes a status into a DB table. So something like:
BTEQ "PRE_MONITORING.sql"

BTEQ "filename.sql"

BTEQ "POST_MONITORING.sql"

That works fine as long as BTEQ returns a zero return code. For != 0 return code the execution of the automic job step stops and the POST_MONITORING step will never be executed. I'm looking for something like a try&catch or continue-on-error but can't find anything like that. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying in a single automic job step?

BTEQ itself has some conditional execution capabilities like IF / ELSEIF / ELSE / ENDIF blocks and IF... THEN GOTO / LABEL which can test a number of status value keywords like ERRORCODE (specific database error) or ERRORLEVEL (severity).

Do you use Automic Workload Automation?
In this case, you can use the post-process tab and there use :MODIFY_STATE to change the return code to 0.
